# Calculating shares squared off in a stock transaction starting from a negative or positive quantity

Tags: php, math, finance

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to check how many shares were 'squared off'/'settled'/'realized' if you started with X number of shares then sold Y, when Y can be greater than X

So for example:

- 10 shares bought - 5 shares sold = Net remaining quantity +5 shares; 5 shares squared off
- 10 shares bought - 15 shares sold = Net remaining quantity -5 shares; 10 shares squared off

Right now my PHP code is

```
$num_squaredoff = 0;
if($transaction_type == 'SELL') {
    if($previous_net_qty > 0) {
        $num_squaredoff = $order_filled_quantity;
        if($num_squaredoff > $previous_net_qty) {
            $num_squaredoff = $previous_net_qty;
        }
    }
}
```

So basically it says "If you have 10 shares, and bought X shares, then X is the number of shares squared off... except if X is more than 10, in which case you squared off 10 shares"

I'm wondering if there's a way to calculate this in cases where the number of sold shares can be any amount -- so the net quantity can end up positive, zero, or negative -- without the if/else statement

I had a thought about using the modulus operator (which would show that eg 10 can't be divided by 15 without a remainder) but not sure if that would help..

PS. I will eventually also use the same logic for short-selling (if you started off with -10 shares and bought 15, then your new net quantity is +5 shares and the number squared off is 10 shares). But the short selling will be handled in a different code block so the same formula/calculation doesn't need to handle starting from both a positive or negative net quantity.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out myself by writing it in function notation. If you started with 10 shares and sold 5, you settled 5 shares. If you started with 10 shares sold 15, you settled 10 shares.

So if you want

- f(10, 5) = 5
- f(10, 15) = 10

Then f(x,y) can just pick the smaller number of x or y

So we can do:

```
$num_squaredoff = min($order_filled_quantity, $previous_net_qty);
```

It's pretty much the same thing my 'if' condition was doing but a little more elegant.